# MySQL select last row each day

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

Trying to select last row each day.

This is my (simplified, more records in actual table) table:

```
+-----+-----------------------+------+
| id  |       datetime        | temp |
+-----+-----------------------+------+
|  9  | 2017-06-05 23:55:00   | 9.5  |
|  8  | 2017-06-05 23:50:00   | 9.6  |
|  7  | 2017-06-05 23:45:00   | 9.3  |
|  6  | 2017-06-04 23:55:00   | 9.4  |
|  5  | 2017-06-04 23:50:00   | 9.2  |
|  4  | 2017-06-05 23:45:00   | 9.1  |
|  3  | 2017-06-03 23:55:00   | 9.8  |
|  2  | 2017-06-03 23:50:00   | 9.7  |
|  1  | 2017-06-03 23:45:00   | 9.6  |
+-----+-----------------------+------+
```

I want to select row with id = 9, id = 6 and id = 3.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT MAX(datetime) Stamp
     , temp 
  FROM weatherdata 
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(DateTime)
     , MONTH(DateTime)
     , DAY(DateTime) 
 order 
    by datetime desc 
 limit 10;
```

But datetime and temp does not match.

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you please elaborate this: *But datetime and temp does not match.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way, which gets the `MAX` date per day and then uses it in the `INNER` query to get the other fields:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE `datetime` IN (
  SELECT MAX(`datetime`) 
  FROM test
  GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`)
 );
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e02b2/2/0)**.

Comment: Darshan Mehta: Perfect! Just want I wanted. O. Jones:  id is autoincrementing and rows are never updated.

Answer (score 2):

If your rows are always inserted and never updated, and if `id` is an autoincrementing primary key, then

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM weatherdata w
  JOIN (   SELECT MAX(id) id
             FROM weatherdata
            GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
       ) last ON w.id = last.id
```

will get you what you want. Why? The inner query returns the largest (meaning most recent) `id` value for each date in `weatherdata`.  This can be very fast indeed, especially if you put an index on the `datetime` column.

But it's possible the conditions for this to work don't hold. If your `datetime` column sometimes gets updated to change the date, it's possible that larger `id` values don't always imply larger `datetime` values.

In that case you need something like this.

```
SELECT w.*
  FROM weatherdata w
  JOIN (   SELECT MAX(datetime) datetime
             FROM weatherdata
            GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
       ) last ON w.datetime = last.datetime
```

Your query doesn't work because it misuses the nasty nonstandard extension to MySQL GROUP BY.  Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

It should, properly, use [the `ANY_VALUE()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) to highlight the unpredictability of the results. It shoud read ....

```
SELECT MAX(datetime) Stamp, ANY_VALUE(temp) temp
```

which means you aren't guaranteed the right row's temp value. Rather, it can return the temp value from any row in each day's grouping.

Comment: Thanks for this proposal.  id is autoincrementing and rows are never updated. Proposal by Darshan worked but I also learned something from yours. I like that your are telling what the query is doing.

Comment: Also tried your proposal (the first) and that is also working fine. Thanks.